# SharePoint 2010 Save list as a template having size more than 500 MB

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list-template

Is there a way to save the list as template that exceeds 500MB size in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 2):

You cant increase more than 500MB as there is limitation of [MaxTemplateDocumentSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice.maxtemplatedocumentsize%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) "A 32-bit integer between 0 and 500 MB."

Below script increase it to 500 MB.

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#For MOSS 2007, Uncomment below two lines
#[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
#[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration")

$webservice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService

#Get the current Maximum Size
$webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize

#Set New Limit and update
$webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize = 1048576000 #1000 MB
$webservice.Update()
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/increase-list-template-maximum-size-in-sharepoint.html#ixzz4TG9z6eWL

Now only option is use the Export-SPweb and Import-SPweb Commands to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you, Waqas for quick reply. I will try this script and let you know.

Comment: It does not work. It looks like SharePoint doesn't let you go beyond 500MB. This is the error message that I get "The specified value for maximum template document size is not valid. Specify a positive number less than 524288000."

Comment: You are correct, A 32-bit integer between 0 and 500 MB. this is limitation of the site.

Comment: So, like I said, is there a way to achieve this? A workaround perhaps?

Comment: only workaround in this case is use export and imprt=spweb

Comment: Ok. I will try that.